# find where in the code an http request was made using chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way using chrome dev tools to find where an http request (ajax) was made?
I have a large project with many requests happening in different files. There's a particular request that I want to be able to inspect, I've found it on the Network tab, but there doesn't seem to be any way to find where in the code was this request started.

Comment: There is the initiator column which will be always `jquery.min.js#1` if `$.ajax` is used. I suppose DevTools reports the script with the line which `xhr.send()` used at.

Comment: The Initiator Column of the Network tab.

Comment: If you have some sort of common AJAX function, you could use a debugging `console.log()` taking advantage of [`arguments.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/caller)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use the **Initiator** column in the **Network** panel. Clicking on the link in the Initiator cell takes you to the line of code where the request was made.

[image: initiator column]

If you can't see it, right-click on the table header and select **Initiator**.

You can also hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while hovering over a resource to see it's initiator. The initiator is green. Dependencies are red. If you can't see the initiator, then it's not currently visible on the table (could be higher up, filtered out, etc.)

[MacPrawn's XHR Breakpoint idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41451994/1669860) is a good approach, too.

Comment: Do you know what it means if `initiator` column, only shows `Other`?

Answer (score 36):

Since you see the request being made in the Network pane, you can grab the url and then add a XHR breakpoint on that URL:

[image: In the breakpoint panel, on the right of the "Sources" pane]

(In the breakpoint panel, on the right of the "Sources" pane)

Hope this helps!